# In R, check if an attribute is in a list for entire column of dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

The following works -

```
3 %in% c(3,4,5) # Returns TRUE
```

If I have a vector of x in a dataframe -

```
x
1
3
5
7
```

How can I generate a TRUE/FALSE vector depending on if x %in c(3,4,5)? Simply using `data['x'] %in c(3,4,5)` does not work is it returns only one value instead of 5.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
data[, "x"] %in% c(3,4,5)
```

or

```
data[["x"]] %in% c(3,4,5)
```

or

```
data$x %in% c(3,4,5)
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

```
d = data.frame(x=c(1,3,5,7),y=c(23,42,1,5))

> d["x"] %in% c(3,4,5)
[1] FALSE

> unlist(d["x"]) %in% c(3,4,5)
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

As Hong says, the following might be simpler:

```
> d[,"x"] %in% c(3,4,5)
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

> d$x %in% c(3,4,5)
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```